# set is not member of boost::PolygonSet

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-polygon

I am trying to overload & operator for PolygonSet but end with following error. I can understand boost::PolygonSet does not have set function but can anyone provide me input to fix this issue. I have tried view_as but did not success.

The code:

```
  Function definition for concept    
    namespace boost { namespace polygon {
         template <>
         struct geometry_concept<boost_geom_api::PolygonSet> {
             typedef polygon_set_concept type;
         }; } }

         PolygonSet PolygonSet::operator&(const PolygonSet& right) const {
             using namespace boost::polygon::operators;
             PolygonSet ps (*this);
             ps &= right;
             return ps;
         }

 PolygonSet& PolygonSet::operator&=(const PolygonSet& right) {
     using namespace boost::polygon::operators;
     using namespace gtl;
     pgns &= right.pgns;
     return (*this); }
```

**Error**:

> ```
> /polygon_set.cpp:160:19:   required from here
> /u/logic/depot/boost_1_57_0/include/boost/polygon/interval_concept.hpp:168:10:
> ```
>
> error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct
>   boost::enable_if,
>   boost::polygon::point_data >’

**Message during compilation**

> /u/logic/depot/boost_1_57_0/include/boost/polygon/detail/polygon_set_view.hpp:198:5:
>   required from ‘geometry_type_1&
>   boost::polygon::self_assignment_boolean_op(geometry_type_1&, const
>   geometry_type_2&) [with geometry_type_1 =
>   std::vector; geometry_type_2 =
>   boost_geom_api::PolygonSet; int op_type = 1]’
>   /u/logic/depot/boost_1_57_0/include/boost/polygon/polygon_set_concept.hpp:419:90:
>   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if::type,
>   typename
>   boost::polygon::is_any_polygon_set_type::type>::type,
>   geometry_type_1>::type&
>   boost::polygon::operators::operator&=(geometry_type_1&, const
>   geometry_type_2&) [with geometry_type_1 =
>   std::vector; geometry_type_2 =
>   boost_geom_api::PolygonSet; typename boost::enable_if
>
> boost::polygon::is_mutable_polygon_set_type::type,
>   typename
>   boost::polygon::is_any_polygon_set_type::type>::type,
>   geometry_type_1>::type = std::vector]’
>   /polygon_set.cpp:160:13:
>   required from here
>   /u/logic/depot/boost_1_57_0/include/boost/polygon/polygon_90_set_traits.hpp:57:51:
>   error: no type named ‘coordinate_type’ in
>   ‘boost::polygon::get_coordinate_type::traits_type {aka struct
>   boost::polygon::polygon_set_traits}’
>
> required from ‘typename boost::enable_if::type,
>   typename
>   boost::polygon::is_any_polygon_set_type::type>::type,
>   geometry_type_1>::type&
>   boost::polygon::operators::operator&=(geometry_type_1&, const
>   geometry_type_2&) [with geometry_type_1 =
>   std::vector; geometry_type_2 =
>   std::vector; typename
>   boost::enable_if::type,
>   typename
>   boost::polygon::is_any_polygon_set_type::type>::type,
>   geometry_type_1>::type = std::vector]’

Comment: Try putting some effort into formatting your question. It's more unreadable than the average Perl code right now.

Comment: done. I am not able to figure out to instantiate temple for Polygon set